# does a <ul> tag automatically cause center alignment within table cell?

Tags: html, css

It is kind of wierd but in my table cell I have a bullet point which for some strange reason it causes the text to align in the center of the cell even though I have no include text-align center or anything of the sort. To be honest all of the other table columns which by the way do not include bullet points align to the left as normal but for the column which contains a bullet points, its causes the text to the align center and I do not know why this is.

My question is does the `<ul>` tag cause the text to align center by default within a table cell or is there something which is somehow contradicting with the `<ul>` tag and hence it is aligning the text to the center?

Below is the table (cut down code):

```
    <table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php
          foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'. ( ( empty ($arrImageFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;

        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is the css which includes css for table:

```
.imagetd{
    font-size:75%;  
}


.qandaul{
    list-style-type:square;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly_container
{
    width:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:500px;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
}

#tableqanda_onthefly td
{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda, #tableqanda_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}       

#tableqanda{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    float:left;
}

#tableqanda td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tableqanda th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

.tableqandarow{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: a) Which text is being centered and b) post your generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Try to check css of cell with firebug..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to common defaults in browsers, a `ul` element is normally displayed as indented. This may depend on different CSS properties in different browsers, so you may need several CSS declarations to remove the indentation. For example, the indentation might take place due to default left padding, or due to default left margin. A fairly safe approach is the following (assuming you wish to remove default vertical spacing around the element, too):

```
ul, ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { margin-left: 1.3em; }
```

The second rule is there to reserve room for the list bullets. The bullet appears on the left of the `li` item content, so some space is needed for it. The value of `1.3em` tends to give a balanced appearance, with roughly equal spacing on the left and on the right of the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

> does the `<ul>` tag cause the text to align center by default within a table cell?

No, the UL tag adds a left-margin, which may cause the list items to appear center.

> is there something which is somehow contradicting with the `<ul>` tag and hence it is aligning the text to the center?

This is possibly the case. Inspect the styles applied to the `<ul>` using a html/css inspector.

Answer (score 0):

```
The <ul> tag adds left margin, in the table cell.
```

Answer (score 0):

The ul tag automatically adds 40px of left padding. Setting the padding to 0 should fix your problem.